# Add and remove class out of menu structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In site has the following menu structure

```
<nav class="menu">
    <li><a href="" class"menu-link">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class"menu-link">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class"menu-link">3</a></li>
</nav>
```

external divs (out of menu), has the following structure

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="itens active">1</div>
    <div class="itens">2</div>
    <div class="itens">3</div>
    <div class="itens">4</div>
</div>
```

how to when a link is clicked, the 'active' class is removed from all three div boxes and then added only to the other div element?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to wrap your <li>'s in a <ul> or <ol>

Comment: `how to When a link is clicked, the 'active' class is removed from all three boxes and then added only to the other div element?` Can you explain this with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. li elements should be only wrapped in UL.

and for add/remove class,you can use:

```
$('.menu li').click(function(){
  $('.container .active').removeClass('active');
  $('.container div:eq('+$(this).index()+')').addClass('active');
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5xe72had/)**

Comment: @MárioDavi: bem-vindo :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind click event to the div elements. Remove the active classes using `.removeClass('active')` , then add the class using `.addClass('active')`

```
$(".container div").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndeb6hnt/2/)

**Edit**

```
$('.menu li').click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.container div').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
});
```

[**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndeb6hnt/4/)

Comment: OP want the active to be toggled on div and not on clicked anchors

Comment: But not when I click on div, but when I click on the related menu :P. Ex: menu-1 clicked added to div-1, when menu-2 clicked remove from all others and them added to div-2

Comment: @MilindAnantwar didnt notice that. Edited the answer

Comment: sorry, I'll edit the post, the structure of the code is not correct

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on your project setup but if you have any libraries or frameworks included , they usually provide methods to find and add/remove classes.

Ex: jquery has methods like addClass/ removeClass and find